# How do you serve client/index.html from server/app.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My file structure:

```
- simulated-selves
  - client
    - index.html
  - server
    - app.js
```

I'm trying to send the user `index.html` when they hit the `/` route.

```
// server/app.js

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/../client/index.html', null, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('error: ', err);
      res.status(err.status).end();
    }
    else res.status(200).end();
  });
});
```

It's not working though. This is the error that gets logged out:

```
error:  { [Error: Forbidden] status: 403 }
```

---

So basically I have access to `__dirname` in `app.js`. Since `app.js` is in the `server` folder, `__dirname` resolves to `/Users/azerner/code/simulated-selves/server`. Since I need to access `index.html` in the `client` folder, I need to manipulate this `__dirname` that I have. I know I could do some string manipulation, but I'm looking for the *best* way to do this.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/../client/index.html` ?

Comment: Yes, it should be `/../client/index.html`! It's still giving me the same error though. And yes - I've restarted my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a node build-in module that deals with resolving path, which might help you with this issue

The function `path.resolve` will deal with the relative part (`/../`) and build an absolute path for you.

For example:

```
var path = require('path');
var clientFile = path.resolve(__dirname + '/../client/index.html');
```

See more info on the documentation on path http://devdocs.io/node/path#path_path_resolve_from_to

Comment: `path.resolve(__dirname, '/../client/index.html')` didn't work, but `path.resolve(__dirname + '/../client/index.html')` did.

Comment: excellent, i wonder why passing each as arguments didnt work.

Comment: Idk, the documentation was hard for me to understand. Could you update your answer please?